# Validate image resolution in Wagtail before uploading

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am currently creating a page in Wagtail that will allow the client to create a new service that has a title, body and a image. What I am asking is, how would one add a validator onto the image before it uploads to check if the image is bigger than a specific size.

So instead of the client being able to upload or select a small image into a header, I can restrict it so the minimum resoltion for that image needs to be 500x500 for example.

I have scratched around and havent been able to find anything of that sorts. I found 1 piece of code [Here](https://gist.github.com/ag-castro/88bd803a43ed80f978453d76b4e7b890) but when I try use that in my code it gives me a error:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got <Image: industrial.jpg>
```

Here is my page model:

```
class WhatWeDoPage(Page):
    """
    The "What We Do" Page or the Services page. This will be the page where
    we showing the services GR-Gear is doing.
    """
    template = 'home/services.html'

    services = StreamField([
        ('services', blocks.StructBlock([
            ('title', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('body', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
            ('image', ImageChooserBlock(required=False, validators=[ImageValidator(width=500, height=500)]))
        ], icone='user'))
    ], blank=True)

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title', classname="full title"),
        StreamFieldPanel('services'),
    ]
```

Any help or assistance would be gladly appreciative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the latest version of Wagtail (2.9 as of writing), your code works perfectly fine. The error in question occurs in `ImageValidator` itself, and what I did to fix that was changing this line under `__call__()`:

```python
img = Image.objects.get(id=image)
```

to this:

```python
img = Image.objects.get(id=image.id)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Cant believe it was something that small and easy to fix haha. Thought it was something way bigger.

Answer (score 1):

From Wagtail 2.9 there is also WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS. Just add to your settings.py

```
WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 500x500
```

See https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/settings.html?highlight=WAGTAILIMAGES_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS#images